# Изменить иконку EXE-файла

Tags: c#, windows, exe

Мне нужно изменить иконку готового exe на другую (из файла) с помощью C#.

P.S. я не разбираюсь в устройстве exe-файлов, задаю вопрос здесь, потому что в  гугле за полтора часа я так ничего и не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Качаем пакет `Ressy` c [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ressy)
- Делаем объект `PortableExecutable` (`var portableExecutable = new PortableExecutable("путь/.exe")`).
- Задаем иконку при помощи метода `SetIcon()`, который принимает `Stream` или путь до `.ico` файла.
- Готово.

Другие возможности можете посмотреть, посетив [GitHub](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/Ressy) проекта. Ну или можете посмотреть там как все устроено, проект полность написан на C# (исходник метода [SetIcon](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/Ressy/blob/8dd06f5a40b4a5d47ea422f7508324c1d64374f6/Ressy/HighLevel/Icons/IconExtensions.cs#L38)).

---

Напомню, что Windows кэширует иконки, если вы поменяли, но ничего не происходит, то подождите, либо попробуйте просто перенести файл в другую папку.

Comment: Скорее всего не получится это сделать, если экзешник подписан сертификатом безопасности, не повредив цифровую подпись.