# Не удается заменить Bitmap в DLL

Tags: c#, windows, .net, dll, resources

Я пытаюсь заменить логотип Windows в файле `basebrd.dll`.
С помощью Resource Hacker я определил, что индекс нужного Bitmap равен `123`.

Мой код:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BrdRR{
    class Program{
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr BeginUpdateResource(string pFileName, bool bDeleteExistingResources);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool UpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, IntPtr lpType, IntPtr lpName, short wLanguage, IntPtr lpData, uint cb);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern bool EndUpdateResource(IntPtr hUpdate, bool fDiscard);

        public static void Main(string[] args){
            byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("Bitmap123.bmp");

            IntPtr handle = BeginUpdateResource("basebrd.dll", false);
            Console.WriteLine(UpdateResource(handle, (IntPtr)2, (IntPtr)123, 1033, GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned).AddrOfPinnedObject(), (uint)data.Length));
            EndUpdateResource(handle, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Но функция `UpdateResource` возвращает `false`, и ничего не заменяется.
Права доступа на файл `basebrd.dll` есть, т.к. это копия, находящаяся в папке с программой.

Я пытался передать в `UpdateResource` строки `"#2"` и `"#123"` для аргументов `lpType` и `lpName`, но это привело лишь к созданию новой "папки" с ресурсами:
[image: скриншот из Resource Hacker]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1468304/220553

Comment: @EvgeniyZ нет желания тащить какие-либо внешние dll с готовым приложением

Comment: 1. Вы тут не один, SO это ресурс, где сообщество собирает полезное не только **авторам**, но и будущим читателям. Вам не нужно, другие будут только рады. 2. Прочитайте внимательно тот ответ, я там упоминал то, что библиотека открыта, и вы без труда можете посмотреть ее код и понять как сделать правильно вашу задумку вручную. Резюмируя - не смотрите на то, что вам дают поверхностно.